# SpriteSheets, CSS, HTML5 and Safari - Why the performance hiccup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

http://kazopark.com/3d/car/

This animation is using a spritesheet.

This animations works completely fine in Firefox and Chrome, as well as the latest versions of IE.

However, when it comes to Safari, it's just not working as you'd expect. The animation speed is incredibly slow, dropping to as little as 15 FPS.

Is there anyway of making something like this work the same across all the browsers, without purposely slowing the others down?

I suspect this is to do with the inadequate way that Safari handles large images?

It should be noted, I have reduced the filesize all the way down to 1.8mb for this, down from 4.3mb. It's still not playing properly.

Code for animation:

```
/********************************
*         INIT ON LOAD          *
*            PUBLIC             *
*********************************/
KMS.background = function(){
var singleton = {};

this.parent;
this.imgHolder;
this.newWidth;
this.newHeight;

function init(){
    parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.className = "KMS_div";
    parent.id = "KMS_div_Background";

    var holder = document.getElementById("KMS_div_Holder");
    holder.appendChild(parent);

    imgHolder = new Image();
    imgHolder.id = "KMS_img_SpriteSheet";
    imgHolder.src = "img/CarRoad_low2.jpg";
    parent.appendChild(imgHolder);

    newWidth = window.innerWidth / 800;
    newHeight = window.innerHeight / 600;

    imgHolder.style.width = 512 + "%";
    imgHolder.style.height = 1365.4 + "%";
}


function BeginBackground(){
    init();

    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        parent.style.left = -(100 * (i % 5)) + "%";
        parent.style.top = -(100 * (parseInt(i / 5) % 14)) + "%";
        i++;

        if(i === 63)    i = 0;

        console.log(i);

    }, 50);

    console.log("BG begin");
};

singleton.BeginBackground = BeginBackground;

return singleton;
}();
```

Comment: i'm not seeing anything back from that url (windows 8 64bit, IE11)

Comment: mm, I've not tested at all on IE yet. I've been hooked up on the Safari issue. I suspect "holder.appendChild(parent);" isn't going to work with IE. I'll take a look and see if I can fix that, for viewing's sake.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th ok that's fixed. Try now?

Comment: This is a really strange way of doing the animation, you should be using css and the `background-position` property instead as it's probably more suited for this kind of thing.

Comment: nope.  still nothing.  I only tried as your question said it would work with the latest IE...  maybe drop that from your text, until you get it working.  Good luck.

Comment: @HugoTunius Do you mean placing the image as a background image, then changing background position? If so, I did indeed try that, to the same result as this unfortunately.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th Strange. It works on Windows 7 IE9, so I just assumed it would be forwards compatible.

Comment: I believe poor performance caused by manipulating `left` and `top` properties. What about having a pure CSS3 method - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lwbIq and your one as a fallback?

Comment: @TigranPetrossian Is it possible to do left then bottom? Or would that need to be done in a similar way to how I do it now?